# Linux - File location

Tags: linux, file

I need a file directory.
I know he is at home / steam / assetto.
But what comes before home?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqSBt.png)

Comment: what do you need? list the file inside a directory? you could use : ls -al command

Comment: I need to know the exact directory of the file.

example in the windowns would be c: /

And on linux?

Comment: on windows =  C:\  On Linux is: /

Comment: I know where the file is, I just need the directory to put it in a .txt

Comment: you could put it at your user directory, /home/youruser/your-created-folder/ , if you using root account, you could put it at /root/your-created-folder/